# How to unit test useFormik onSubmit in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library, formik

I have a react component called **Subscribe.js**. It has its own custom hook that takes care of the business logic. In that hook, I am using the `useFormik` hook to set up validations and onSubmit for the form in the **Subscribe.js** component.

**How do I test the form submission functionality?**

Here is what I have done so far

```js
 it("should complete form submission", async () => {
    const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
    render(<Subscribe />);

    const inputElement = screen.getByPlaceholderText("Enter your email");

    userEvent.type(inputElement, "abc@gmail.com");
    const submitButton = screen.getByRole("button", { name: /submit/i });
    userEvent.click(submitButton);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(handleSubmit).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
```

This is my test and I am referencing the example given on the official docs of the react testing library.

Here is my **Subscribe.js** component

```js
import React from "react";
import {  Button, Form } from "react-bootstrap";
import useSubscribe from "./../../hooks/useSubscribe";
import { FormField } from "./../FormField/FormField";
function Subscribe() {
  const { formik, isLoading } = useSubscribe();
  return (
        <Form  onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
         
              <FormField
                type="Email"
                className="w-100"
                placeholder="Enter your email"
                isInvalid={formik.errors.email}
                isValid={formik.touched.email && !formik.errors.email}
                error={formik.errors.email}
                {...formik.getFieldProps("email")}
              />
           
              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="primary"
                size="lg"
                className="btn btn-primary btn-lg px-4 mb-2"
                onClick={formik.handleSubmit}
              >Submit
              </Button>
        </Form>
  );
}

export default Subscribe;
```

Here is my **useSubscribe** hook that is responsible for form submission and validations.

```js
import { useFormik } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const useSubscribe = () => {

  const initialValues = {
    email: "",
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: initialValues,
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      email: Yup.string().email("Invalid Email").required("Email is required"),
    }),
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
   // call to backend with values
  });
  return {
    formik,
  };
};

export default useSubscribe;
```